# Attempting to link a plane with cloth sim to an object with rigid body

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision

[image]

Hi,

I'm attempting to link this plane (with cloth sim) to the chain link above (both have rigid body). Whenever I play the animation the cloth just falls through the chain link above and they do not react to each other (I've tried adding the collision modifier to both objects too).

Thanks very much

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you provide more information? How did you try it? Using modifiers? And if so which and how are they setup?

Comment: One way to handle this is to use "pinning" on the cloth sim to pin one or a small number of vertices (near where the cloth meets the chain), then parent the cloth mesh to the lowest link of the chain.  The pinned vertices of the cloth will follow the motion of the chain link, and the unpinned vertices will follow the motion of the pined ones and the cloth sim.

Comment: @risingfall I think you should post that as an answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make a new vertex group composed by the vertices nearest to the chain surface, and then check the pinning option and selecting such vertex group:
[image]

Have a nice day.

Comment: I never knew there was such pinning in the setting. Thank you.